# Vim preview css color in comments

Tags: css, vim, vim-plugin

Im using [Skammer's plugin](https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color) to preview color in css files using Vim.
 But it does not preview colors in comments. 
 How can I enable this?

Comment: Of course it is what im doing. But I don want to loose time uncommenting and comment just to see the colors while im developing and testing. Im using a pallet of color in my css and these are in comments, so to pickup the right color I need to uncomment and comment always and I want to find way to do not loose time with this.

Comment: Put the colours in a class name that never gets used in your HTML.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this on your own. The plugin author should be capable of making the change, though. Since his plugin is hosted on github, you should post a feature request on the issue tracker: https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin seems to do the trick: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3567